# What is the best way to find the Inverse Laplace with Convolution Theorem?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, convolution, dirac-delta

I have to calculate the inverse laplace using Convolution, but I get stuck when I have to integrate with the delta dirac.
$$F(s)=\frac{s}{s^{2}+2s+2}$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{s^2+2s+2} = \frac{a}{s-b}+\frac{c}{s-d} = \mathcal{L}[a e^{-bt} 1_{t >0}+c e^{-dt}1_{t >0}]$ ,$ s = \mathcal{L}[-\delta'(t)]$, $\frac{s}{s^2+2s+2}=\mathcal{L}[-\delta'(t) \ast (a e^{-bt} 1_{t >0}+c e^{-dt}1_{t >0})] = -(a+b) \delta(t)+ab e^{-bt} 1_{t >0}+c de^{-dt}1_{t >0}$. That $\lim_{s \to \infty} F(s)=0$ implies $a+b=0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You don't need convolution, write
$$F(s)=\frac{s}{s^{2}+2s+2}=\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}$$

Comment: I know, but it is a requirement to solve using convolution

Comment: I multiplied the function by one, but the inverse laplace of 1 is the delta dirac

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$F(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+2s+1}=s\times\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}$$
but you cannot use convolution theorem on this as by definition:
$$\mathscr{L}\left[f(t)\right]\ne s$$
and so it is difficult to prove this problem using convolution theorem like this, although this question is a good demonstration of shift theorem?

---

$$F(s)=\frac{(s+1)}{(s+1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}$$
and since:
$$\mathscr{L}\left[e^{at}f(t)\right]=F(s-a)$$
we can easily see that:
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{(s+1)}{(s+1)^2+1}\right]=e^{-t}\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^2+1}\right]$$
and this makes finding $f(t)$ much easier

Comment: In the exam I had to do it like that but then it asked to redo the problem using convolution